# how to run a scheduled task in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I want to run a

> timer

in selenium webdriver,I don't want to use multi-thread, and the timer cann't block(like setInterval in js),and now I have no idea.

Eg: check a element class per 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you use python,you can write a simple script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# filename:scheduler.py
#encoding:utf-8
import time

def scheduler():
    while True:
        # to something here
        print 'hello world'

        time.sleep(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler()
```

run:python scheduler.py

Comment: This will block the main thread, and I cann't do any operation.

Answer (score 0):

If your selenium script consists only of checking an element class, then you can execute your selenium script as a cronjob, i.e., run a java class as a cron task. Or you can go for TimerTask which comes under java.util. Quartz is also a nice scheduler.

**Links for cron job:**
[How to configure cron jobs](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/)
[Running a java program as cron job](http://www.coderanch.com/t/615718/Linux-UNIX/Running-Java-Program-Cron-job)
[Cron job examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/)

**Link for TimerTask:**
[Timer Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html)

**Link for Quartz:**
[Quartz Tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/)

Event though your current scope is specific, you can think of using the above for scheduling your automation test suite to run after specific interval. Easy way to achieve nightly automation.

Comment: +1, this is a nice solution. Also, use Windows Task Scheduler. Many many libraries and tools exist for this very reason, don't roll your own!

Comment: My question is run a timer in a webdriver(like setInterval in js), not how to run the webdriver automatic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java,this might help..

```
for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
if(driver.findElement(By.id("id_of_element")).isDisplayed())   //you can also use selector,class name,xpath..etc instead of id
{
 break;
}
Thread.sleep(10000);//sleep for 10 secs
}
```

the above code will check for element's presence every 10secs, if found it'l come out of for loop...

Comment: This will block the main thread, and I cann't do any operation.

Comment: What else would you want to do while you are taking an interval between the element class verifications?

Comment: Almost everything, such as click button, query element css class, fill input and submit